# clang-format How to stop breaking long macros into new lines

Tags: clang-format

I have a macro,

```
#define MSG_m(lvl, ostr) if(lvl > (static_cast<int>(params.diagnostics) - 2)); else {std::ostringstream ost; ost << getHierarchicalName() << ": " << ostr; message(ost.str(), lvl);}
```

I have my .clang-format settings

```
    ---
Language: Cpp
BasedOnStyle: WebKit
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: false
AlignOperands: false
AlignTrailingComments: true
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
BreakBeforeInheritanceComma: true
BreakStringLiterals: false
ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: false
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
FixNamespaceComments: true
NamespaceIndentation: All
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 1
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 0
PenaltyBreakComment: 100
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 2
PenaltyBreakString: 1000
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 1
ReflowComments: false
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: true
IndentCaseLabels: 'true'
...
```

and when I use format from vscode , the macro gets split on multiple lines , I want to prevent this only for macros.

Comment: @Danny no luck so far